# Why is PIN24 (and others) sending binarys on fresh system

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I am planning to use the spi0 of the raspberry 4 B+. My system is super fresh:
[image]

1. Factory-new Raspberry just unboxed
2. Flashed Raspian
3. Booted Raspberry
4. Connected my Digital analyser
5. PIN24 is sending some undifined binarys

For the use of SPI0 i need PIN24 as the chip selection pin.

Why is it sending and what is it sending? What kind of Protocol is it?

[image]

Comment: Raspbian is a 32bit OS. Don't know this Raspian.

Answer (score 1):

On an unmodified system GPIO 8 (pin 24) will be configured as an input.

It will have weak pulls to ground enabled but in effect it is floating - especially if your probe wires are acting like an aerial.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. My analyser was not connected to the raspberry ground. So everything was floating.
Once grounded it shows me the correct spi signals.